Custom 3D Coordinate System in pgfplots
I am trying to create a custom 3D coordinate system using pgfplots in LaTeX. I want to define three direction vectors x, y, and z. However, when I define x=(-0.35,-0.35) and then define y and z, the system uses the newly defined x, which is inconvenient and cumbersome. Is there a better way to handle this situation?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,thick,line cap=round,line join=round,
    % Define some interesting colors
    vertex/.style={circle,fill=black,inner sep=0.2pt,minimum size=0.2pt},
    edge/.style={-,draw=black},
    dashededge/.style={dashed,draw=black},
    z={(0,1)},y={(1,0)},x={(-0.353553,0,-0.353553)},]
    
    % Define the coordinates
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (1,0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,1,0);
    \coordinate (P) at (0,0,1);
    
    % Draw the visible edges
    \draw[edge] (P) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
    
    % Draw the hidden edges
    \draw[dashededge] (A) -- (P);
    \draw[dashededge] (B) -- (A);
    \draw[dashededge] (C) -- (A);
    
    % Draw the vertices
    \node[vertex] at (A) [label=160:$A$] {};
    \node[vertex] at (B) [label=225:$B$] {};
    \node[vertex] at (C) [label=0:$C$] {};
    \node[vertex] at (P) [label=90:$P$] {};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


We are accustomed to defining coordinate axes such that the x-axis points to the bottom left of the page, the y-axis points to the right of the page, and the z-axis points upward from the page. However, the default coordinate system in TikZ defines the x-axis pointing to the right, the y-axis pointing upward, and the z-axis pointing downward and to the left. I would like to modify the TikZ 3D coordinate system to match our customary orientation as described. Could you please suggest a convenient way to achieve this? Thank you!

It seems that setting z={(0,1)}, y={(1,0)}, x={(-0.35,0,-0.35)} works. Are there any other methods?

You do not want to define the axis in terms of the old coordinates. -that means you need units cm. Actually you do not want to mess with the coordinate system at all unless you need non-rectangular coordinates. Use the view option to rotate the system.

Please always provide a minimal working example.

You don't appear to be using pgfplots at all?

Is the objection to having to define x last? I'm a bit confused about what the problem is. I'm also a bit confused by @hpekristiansen's suggestions, though I realise there was less information in the question at that point. Not sure what view refers to? Are you aware of tikz-3dplot? I am not sure it is a good option in this case, but maybe worth a look. It has some bugs, but it can be very useful. I'm not sure it would be great to be using it to set up what amounts to your default configuration, though.

@cfr: As written, view is an option to rotate the coordinate system. It is quite common option used in many PGFPlots (indicated in OP title and tags).

@hpekristiansen but not in the code. (but that may not even have been in the question when you wrote the comment.)
